Typescript typeof of a generic variable
I have built a generic function in my program that accepts an array of Type. In some cases, the Type could be Date, sometimes it might be something else.
function processArray<Type>(arr: Type[]) {
  if (arr instanceof Array<Date>) { // error
    arr.map(x => x.getFullYear());
  }
}

How could I guess the type? Checking the typeof or instanceof of the array doesn't work. I have an idea of storing the type in an attribute, but I think there should be a better way than creating an attribute and storing the type.

Have you considered Using type predicates?

@Anton I'll try to implement it using type predicates.
@jcalz maybe Diamond Notation is a concept more known to java developers. By diamond notation I mean the two minor and major signs before and after the type of a generic which resemble a diamond.
i.e. <string>

• Okay, I've edited the title to use conventional TS terminology. • Please consider [edit]ing the code to be a [mre] we could copy and paste into our own IDEs to work on it. Right now this is just an excerpt of code and not a self-contained example, so most of the things in there would just be errors in anyone else's IDEs. If the question is just "how can I determine at runtime what Type is, given a value of Array<Type>" then you should be able to provide an example with just built-in TypeScript things, maybe like this playground link shows.

(see prev comment). So the only way to do this at runtime is either to store some extra data (like your attribute) or to actually test every element of the array. Given my example with Date[], you'd write a type guard function as shown here. There's no shortcut here; TypeScript's type system is erased (just like Java's generics) so there's no "type" at runtime to check. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz Yes, thanks for answering my question. If you want, you can write an answer, I'll accept it and upvote it.

I will write an answer but can you [edit] the question to give a [mre] (or let me know if it's okay if I do it) such as the Date one in my link above? Right now I can't possibly write an answer about whatever NewsArticle is because I don't have that code.

Sure, you can do it if you have the time and wish to edit it. I don't have anything against it.

This question is similar to: How to check instance of the generic in Array with Typescript. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@jcalz You've already answered this one :).

It's a little different since this is an arbitrary generic type argument and not just some set of known things, but it's very similar.

I have taken a look at the type predicates and seen the type guard example. I think that wrapping the array in a special object and creating an attribute which tells the type during runtime would be a tad bit more performant solution since it wouldn't have to check all of the elements in the array. There aren't so many it would be a problem for a modern computer (we are talking about 60, 70 elements), but i think I like that kind of solution more. Thanks to everyone for the help.

TypeScript's type system, including generic type arguments is erased when TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript. There's no runtime type information to look at.  You can't write anything like arr instanceof Array<Date> since that's just arr instanceof Array at runtime, and it's always going to be true, no matter what. You should think of what you need to see happen at runtime and then write that code.

As you mentioned, you could add some piece of data that encodes the type of the element, such as a type property, and accept a union of acceptable types:
type MyData =
  { type: "Date", array: Date[] } |
  { type: "string", array: string[] } | 
  // other specific cases you want to handle...
  { type: "unknown", array: unknown[] }

function processArray(data: MyData) {
  if (data.type === "Date") {
    data.array.map(x => x.getFullYear());
  }
}

That works but it requires you to actually pass in that extra piece of data:
processArray({ type: "Date", array: [new Date()] });

And it's really not necessary for the function to be generic anymore, since you have a finite list of cases you can handle, and you let all the other ones be "unknown".  You could still use generics if you must, though:
function processArray<T>(data: MyData & { array: T[] }) {
  if (data.type === "Date") {
    data.array.map(x => x.getFullYear());
  }
}


If you don't want to change your data, then your only option is to perform some kind of runtime test of the array. The only safe one would be to check every element of the array (since it's possible for a generic array to hold heterogeneous data, like ["a", new Date(), 123]) and then act only if every element is of the expected type:
function processArray<T>(arr: T[]) {
  if (arr.every(x => x instanceof Date)) {
    arr.map(x => x.getFullYear());
  }
}

This relies on the fact that TypeScript treats the every() array method as a type guard function which narrows the array element type if it returns true.
This is easy to call, since you don't need to add any new data:
processArray([new Date()]);

but you are doing a bunch more work at runtime. If it's a large array, that might matter to you.

It's up to you which general approach to take: keep your data structure but perform an extensive runtime test, or change your data structure. Either way, you need to do these things yourself, since the TypeScript type system does not exist at runtime.
Playground link to code
